# Need to split a text word by word or by symbol for a lexic analyzer, i cant separate "()" without space

Tags: java, regex

[Lexic Analizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ45y.png)
[image]

The problem is:

When I try to split the word with the code:

```
String[] palabras = textoLexema.getText().split("\\b|\\s+");
```

It gets separated as in the image and it doesnt separete symbols that are together(without space in between).

I was wondering if anyone can help me come up with a regex that can separate them with or without space those symbols

Comment: Do you have any sample strings? Please post input/expected output

Comment: Don't use the split method, use the find method with: `\w+|[^\s\w]`

Comment: Try to split with `split("\\W+")`

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys thanks for the help i fixed it by creating an Array from the word "){" after that I splitted that symbol by symbol an re-evaluated what they were.

```
if (palabraSinEspacios.matches("[{|}|\\[|\\]|\\(|\\)|\\;]+")) {
            //Separa delimitadores si vienen pegados segunda evaluacion
            String[] palabraSeparada = palabras[i].split("\\s*");
            for (int j = 0; j < palabraSeparada.length; j++) {
                //Filtar el arreglo de la paalabra separada por si contiene 
                //Espacios los remplaza 
                String palbraSinsEspacioSeparada = palabraSeparada[j].trim().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                if (palbraSinsEspacioSeparada.equals("")) {
                    //Si la palabra no existe la salta y brinca al else
                } else {
                    listModelPatron.addElement("Delimitador con literales: " + palabraSeparada[j]);
                    listModelToken.addElement("Delimitador:    " + palabraSeparada[j]);
                }
            }
        }
```